# WP8 Update(tileData) does not update live tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I'm having an issue in my app when I try to update a secondary live tile.

```
            tile.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri(smallFPath, UriKind.Absolute);
            tile.BackgroundImage = new Uri(largeFPath, UriKind.Absolute);
            if (largeBPath != "DISABLED") { tile.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(largeBPath, UriKind.Absolute); }
            tile.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri(wideFPath, UriKind.Absolute);
            if (wideBPath != "DISABLED") { tile.WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri(wideBPath, UriKind.Absolute); }
            tile.BackContent = string.Empty;
            tile.BackTitle = string.Empty;
            tile.Count = 0;
            tile.Title = string.Empty;
            tile.WideBackContent = string.Empty;

            secondTile.Update(tile);
```

Images are rendered just before this and are saved to Isolated Storage. The file path changes each time, and old images are regularly deleted.

The problem is that the tile doesn't update. So say the large image says "tile created" when I create the tile, when I make a new image that says "tile updated", it never switched. It always stays at "tile created".

Comment: It also should be noted that if the user resizes the tile, and waits for tile to flip, the new images are shown. However, this is not ideal as the user would have to constantly be resizing the tile when they want to see updated info.

Comment: This seems to only happen when I acquire images from the internet. Even if I use a webclient to save the images to isolated storage, these images from the web cause the tile not to update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue - if you use a web image when you create your tile, your tile will be frozen and you will never be able to update it again.

Full post here: http://www.baileystein.com/2014/01/25/windows-phone-8-flip-tile-bug/